# Air Leaks Where Floor Meets Baseboard

Tags: insulation, caulking

Wondering if anyone had any suggestions to stop air leaks where floor meets baseboard. Is caulking the best way to go?

The room with the air leaks has a cold floor anyway as it sits over an non heated stairway, but stopping the leaks would be a good step in the right direction toward a bit more comfort.

Thanks!

Jam[image]

Comment: What type of floor?

Comment: Don’t know the species, but hard wood floor.

Comment: That's not the place to seal an airflow problem. You'll just move it somewhere else. Find out where the air is actually coming from (at the outer building envelope) and seal it there.

Answer (score 1):

I will install shoe molding, caulk, and paint

It will look natural and caulking will do the sealing

Comment: Hello. The weather is warming a bit this weekend and looking to do the shoe molding with caulk. I have the materials. Wondering if I would calk before putting shoe molding on, after, or both? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Caulk would do a great job of sealing the cracks but only if the floor is nailed down to a sub floor. Most manufacturers do not recommend sealing ends of floating floors because they have to expand and contract. If using caulk use the smallest bead possible, not a large bead like you'd use in a shower or tub. Good luck.

Comment: Also worth seeing if it is possible to get *underneath* the floor - some low-expansion foam behind the skirting would be good.

Comment: I wish I could get underneath the floor but not too sure how to do it.

Comment: That doesn't look like a floating floor to me, it looks like actual, solid hardwood. Of course, looks can be deceiving...